# How can I fix jumping in the air?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D platformer with Unity. I used [this](https://youtu.be/vFsJIrm2btU) tutorial  to write this code but changed it a little bit. I want to support both keyboard and gamepad, so I use the new Input System. I've defined three variables called GroundedRememeber, JumpPressedRemember and JumpPressedRememberTime and basically they work like timers and check if the player leaves the ground and then the player can jump when he is near the ground without need to touch it and I want to use it instead of famous "groundCheck". But the problem is that these timers are not working and the player can jump forever even in the air when I press jump button rapidly. Also, as you can see, I added a LayerMask named "groundLayers" for the player to jump only on this type of objects but when I choose "Ground" in the "groundLayers" slot in the Inspector, the player can't jump anymore.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions
 {
   private PlayerInputActions controls; 
   [SerializeField] LayerMask groundLayers;     
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Animator anim;
   private bool facingRight = true;
   private Vector2 moveInput;
  [SerializeField] private float jumpForce;
    float JumpPressedRemember = 0;
   
   [SerializeField] float JumpPressedRememberTime = 0.2f;
    float GroundedRemember = 0;
     
   [SerializeField]  float GroundedRememberTime = 0.25f;  
   [SerializeField]  float HorizontalAcceleration = 1;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingBasic = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenStopping = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenTurning = 0.5f;
   [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float JumpHeight = 0.5f;

   private void Awake() 
   {
      controls = new PlayerInputActions();

      controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this);
    }
     void Start()
    {
      rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
      anim = GetComponent<Animator>();       
}
   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
      moveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
          
   }
    void Jump() {
     rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Force);
     GroundedRemember = 0;
     JumpPressedRemember = 0;
   }

  bool TryJump() {
    if (GroundedRemember > 0) {
        Jump();
        return true;
    } else {
        JumpPressedRemember = JumpPressedRememberTime;
        return false;
    }
}
   void PlayerInputActions.IPlayerActions.OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
   {
       jumpForce = context.ReadValue<float>();
       switch (context.phase) {
            case InputActionPhase.Performed:
               TryJump();
               break;
       }
   }
  void FixedUpdate()
  {

   if(facingRight == false && moveInput.x > 0){
   
    Flip();
   
   }else if (facingRight == true && moveInput.x < 0){
    
    Flip();

   }
 }
    void Flip(){
    
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
    
 }  
 void OnEnable()
 {
     controls.Enable();
 }
 
 void OnDisable()
{
    controls.Disable();
}
 void Update()
  {

   Vector2 GroundedBoxCheckPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0, -0.01f);
   Vector2  GroundedBoxCheckScale = (Vector2)transform.localScale + new Vector2(-0.02f, 0);
   bool Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(GroundedBoxCheckPosition, transform.localScale, 0, groundLayers);
    
    GroundedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Grounded)
    {
      GroundedRemember = GroundedRememberTime;
    }

    JumpPressedRemember -= Time.deltaTime; 
  
    if ((JumpPressedRemember > 0)) {
      TryJump();
    }

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    
     float HorizontalVelocity = rb.velocity.x;
      HorizontalVelocity += moveInput.x;
          
        if (Mathf.Abs(moveInput.x) < 0.01f)
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenStopping, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
           else if (Mathf.Sign(moveInput.x) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity))
           HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        else
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingBasic, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalVelocity, rb.velocity.y);    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how much the player jumps for, then try maybe adding a delay to the next jump

Maybe using the `Invoke()` function ur just using Coroutines if you know how to use them.

But i would still recommend using a Ground Check since it's practical and just easier and i don't see a reason why you wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The player can jump forever if I press the jump button rapidly. For the Ground Check, as you can see, I attached a link to the tutorial that I used in the question. If you see it, you will find out why I want to use this. But if I want to explain it quickly, I have to say that I want to use this because it makes the game more responsive. Ground Check checks if you're on the ground and if so, you can jump but if you're not on the ground but just near it like in centimeters, you can't jump and that's my problem.